# How to host nodejs typescript project on cpanel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am hosting node js app first time so I want some guidance.

I do not have any idea only saying after hosting 503

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily busy, try again later!

Please guide me how to host typescript node js app on control panel.

Comment: can you share more informantion?

Comment: What is the precise hosting provider and hosting plan you have?  Some hosting plans do not allow the running of nodejs because they don't allow long running processes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).